CWDM-like 10G transceivers at homelab - feasible?
I am happily running homelab on single mode fiber at 10G.
I was always curious to see CWDM working, and CWDM mux/demux modules are getting very affordable.
Is there some hobby-friendly way to get tunable wavelength in transceivers? My observation is that modules where you can dial in wavelength are >1k$, and I am definitely not going to use these. Are there modules where you can adjust temperature/current and therefore set wavelength good enough for coarse CWDM mux/demux?
Or the only practical way is to get fixed wavelength modules tuned at the factory?

That's pretty much the price tag, even with 3rd-party suppliers - tunable means DWDM though usually. However, CWDM/DWDM setups aren't really that interesting - when the components match it 'just' works. Are there specific aspects you're trying to research?

@Zac67 No specific interest, I hope to find "hackable" modules which you can adjust.
